# Representing that a Player has played for the same team over multiple years in a property graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, property-graph

Below is the property graph model I am planning to use to represent various sports leagues. I am wondering the best approach to represent the fact that a Player has played for the same team over multiple years. For e.g. John might have been playing with Broncos in 2011, 2012 and 2013.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the same relationship type connected to the same nodes multiple times.

```
Player1 -[r:BELONGED_TO] -> Team1
Player1 -[q:BELONGED_TO] -> Team1
r.in_year = 2009
q.in_year = 2009
```